# Amplify remove auth - Resource cannot be removed because it has a dependency on another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Original user pool was imported. Trying to remove imported user pool to replace with new one. I've tried running `amplify update auth` and `amplify remove auth` to no success

> Auth has already been imported to this project and cannot be modified
> from the CLI. To modify, run "amplify remove auth" to unlink the
> imported auth resource. Then run "amplify add auth".

Following the above, when I run `amplify remove auth` I get

> Resource cannot be removed because it has a dependency on another
> resource

Comment: Try Amplify Studio from the AWS console and remove it using the UI.

Comment: @Kaneki21 This doesn't seem to be an option in Amplify studio

Comment: So I deleted the auth from Amplify Studio as well as from cognito, and I'm getting the option to start from scratch. Can you please create a dummy app in amplify and test a little bit. You should be able to find the solution

Comment: @Kaneki21 Yea thats the issue that is documented and one im trying to avoid. This is an imported Auth so the CFN is not created. Having to re-create the app from scratch is exactly what I need to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this error by removing "Auth" records from backend/amplify-meta.json and backend/backend-config.json files.